# Is the change of basis matrix a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a change of basis matrix T on the vector space $R^3$. Can one say that there is a Isomorphism from $R^3 \rightarrow R^3 $ given by this matrix T?

Comment: One can say that if one is willing to abuse terminology (compare the two answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An isomorphism from $\Bbb R^3$ into $\Bbb R^3$ is a bijective linear map. And matrices are not linear maps. Therefore, the answer is negative.

However, if $T$ is a change of basis matrix, the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R^3&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^3\\v&\mapsto&M.v\end{array}$$*is* a linear map, which happens to be an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes I meant the linear map that can be created with this matrix, sry for not including this

Answer (score 0):

Of course, $T$ is linear.

Now suppose there are some vectors $v,w$ such that $T(v)=T(w)\Rightarrow T(v-w)=0$. Express $v,w$ in your initial basis $u_1,u_2,u_3$: $v=\alpha_1u_1+\alpha_2u_2+\alpha_3u_3, w=\beta_1u_1+\beta_2u_2+\beta_3u_3$. Then $T(v-w)=T((\alpha_1-\beta_1)u_1+(\alpha_2-\beta_2)u_2+(\alpha_3-\beta_3)u_3)=(\alpha_1-\beta_1)T(u_1)+(\alpha_2-\beta_2)T(u_2)+(\alpha_3-\beta_3)T(u_3)=0$.

We have that $\{T(u_1),T(u_2),T(u_3)\}$ is a basis by hypotheis, so they are linear independent, implying $(\alpha_i-\beta_i)=0$ for $i=1,2,3$, hence $v=w$ and $T$ is one-to-one.

Now take some vector $w$. We can express it with the final base $w=\gamma_1T(u_1)+\gamma_2T(u_2)+\gamma_3T(u_3)$. Consider the vector $v=\gamma_1u_1+\gamma_2u_2+\gamma_3u_3$. Then $T(v)=\gamma_1T(u_1)+\gamma_2T(u_2)+\gamma_3T(u_3)=w$, so $T$ is surjective.

We conclude $T$ is an isomorphism.

Note that this can be generalized for a change of basis in $R^n$ given by some matrix $T$.

Comment: Does this answer your question?